# split by newline - returns an array containing the original String if no matches

Tags: regex, ruby

I recently discovered that`String#split` method returns a one-element array with the original string in it if no matches found:

```
"azerty keyboard".split(/\n/)
=> ["azerty keyboard"] 

"azerty keyboard".split(',')

=> ["azerty keyboard"]
```

What would be a solution to not split if there are no matches found? Just use:

```
if "azerty keyboard".match(/\n/)
...# split here
end
```

or there is a better way?

Comment: Or `"azerty".include?("\n")`

Comment: What good is a conditional before the fact when the size of the resultant array tells you that outcome and incurs no substantial overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're playing with Ruby, you could open up the `String` class and create a new function that works the way you expect:

```rb
class String
  def split_if(matches)
    match(matches) ? split(matches) : self
  end
end
```

Which would then return:

```rb
"azerty keyboard".split_if(/\n/)
=> "azerty keyboard"

"azerty keyboard".split_if(' ')
=> ["azerty", "keyboard"]
```

Although keep in mind that just because we *can*, doesn't always mean we *should*. Some folks think opening up classes is a big no-no. So *should* you do this? That's up to you, your team and the needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you wouldn't run this if you know what the string already contains but assume you have a string object:

```
string = "azerty keyboard"
split_string = string.split(/\n/) if string.include?("\n")
=>nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also give `match` a block instead of using the `if` statement:

```
str = 'azerty keyboard'
str.match(/\n/) {|m| str.split(m[0])} || str
```